# Sub-Resources in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

I'm trying to migrate my server from jax-rs to spring mvc.

My rest model is that I have entities of type A with unique ID, and entities of type B with unique ID, but each entity B is belong to one and only one entity A (one-to-many).

So the API support many URLs like /A/{a_id}/B/{b_id} and also, /B/{b_id}

The implementation in jax-rs was a resource B, and a resource A with a reference to the B resource.

```
@Component
@Path("A/{id_a}")
class ResourceA {
    @Resource("B")
    ResourceB resourceB;

    @Path("B/b_id")
    public ResourceB getResourceB() {
        return resourceB;
    }

    // ... additional A's request handlers
}
```

I read some questions and articles about spring MVC, and I understand that jax-rs-like sub-resources is not supported in spring MVC. The sub resource contains many methods, and using method delegation is almost not feasible.

also, this is only the beginning, since A contains also entities C, D and E...

Is there a better way to solve it in Spring MVC?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find any way to do this?